# Angular 8 ng-bootstrap modal not loading CSS classes

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ng-bootstrap

I npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@5.3.1 in an Angular 8 project, When I open the modal using the modal service, the first try the modal will take time to open. the second time the modal does not open. Looking at the devtool, the modal is open just doesn't have CSS classes set. I did import bootstrap to the styles.scss file `@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";` I tried using JavaScript to inject the CSS classes after open the model but didn't make any difference.

```
   @ViewChild('modalContent', { static: false }) private modalContent: TemplateRef<any>;
   // .....some code here....

    public openNgbModal(): NgbModalRef {
      return this.modalService.open(this.modalContent, {
        size: 'lg',
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false,
        windowClass : 'modal-content'
      });
    }
```

See below:

[image]

The correct html should be the below:
[image]

Comment: do you import bootstrap scripts in `angular.json`?

Comment: yes, i did import the scripts

Comment: can you see in F12 if file was loaded

Comment: Also why you use `return`? and maybe try `.show`

Comment: i'm using version 5 of ng-bootstrap (angular 8) doesn't have ``.show``. i'm using return because i'm calling that function to open a model instead of calling ``this.modalService.open`` every time

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the modalService.open() without any options and see if it make any difference.

```
this.modalService.open(this.modalContent)
```

Comment: should be a comment

Comment: Unfortunately, my reputation is not that high to put comment directly on the posted question.

Answer (score 0):

Im not proud of the answer but it did get the job done. Used javascript to add the classes manual.

```
   public openNgbModal(): NgbModalRef {
      return this.modalService.open(this.modalContent, {
        size: 'lg',
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false,
        windowClass : 'modal-content'
      });

      const modalBackdrop = document.getElementsByTagName('ngb-modal-backdrop');
      // check the class if exists
      modalBackdrop[0].className = 'modal-backdrop fade show';
      
      const modalWindow = document.getElementsByTagName('ngb-modal-window');
      // check the class if exists
      modalWindow[0].className = 'modal fade show d-block';
      modalWindow[0].setAttribute('aria-modal', 'true');
      modalWindow[0].children[0].className = 'modal-dialog modal-s';
    }
```